# browser is not catching given url when i am running the step definition file in protractor-cucumber

Tags: protractor

I am new to this protractor-cucumber.please correct me if i am going wrong.
i am using protractor 3.2.2
when i am run feature file, it gives correct output.but when i am run step definition, the browser not taking the given url.

My feature file is given below.

```
Feature: Login page test   
Scenario: Verify whether the user is able to view the login page while 
giving the URL.   
Given I go to "http://localhost:4200/login"       
When The URL of the page should be "http://localhost:4200/login"
```

---

My step definition file is given below.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function() {

this.Given('I go to {string}', function (string) {
browser.get(string);
});
this.When('The URL of the page should be {string}', function (string) {
expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(string);
});
}
```

---

My config. file is given below

```
exports.config = {
seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', 
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
specs: [ 
'features/*.feature'    
],  
capabilities: {  
'browserName': 'chrome'    
},  
directConnect: true,  
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/login',
framework: 'custom',
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

cucumberOpts: {  
require: 'features/step_definitions/*.js',   
tags: false,
format: 'pretty',
profile: false,
'no-source': true
}  };
```

---

The error showing when i am run 'protractor protractor.conf.js' is given below.

```
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
(node:7508) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use 
os.tmpdir() instead.
[7884:6800:1229/145724.847:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(107)] 
Failed to launch GPU process.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12425/devtools/browser/74f2a81c-51c2-
4a8a-afec-26166a388d1f

C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\se
lenium-webdriver\http\index.js:365
  onError(new Error(message));
          ^
Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54206
at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\http\index.js:365:15)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
at acquireSession (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protrac
tor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:62:22)
at Function.createSession (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:295:12)
at new Driver (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\selenium-webdriver\chrome.js:778:38)
at DirectDriverProvider.getNewDriver (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\built\driverProviders\direct.js:69:16)
at Runner.createBrowser (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\built\runner.js:203:37)
at C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\runner
.js:293:21
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
at C:\Users\CS1027C\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules
\q\q.js:556:49
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error message: 
   Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:54206,

your issue should caused by using lower chromedriver with higher Chrome browser,  upgrade the chromedriver should fix your problem.

And change the cucumberOpts in your config file as below:

```
cucumberOpts: {
    monochrome: true,
    strict: true,
    plugin: ["pretty"],
    require: [
        'features/step_definitions/*.js'
    ],
    tags: ''
}
```

Change your step defintion file as below: **(if you use Cucumber 1 or below)**

```
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
var expect = chai.expect;

module.exports = function() {

    this.Given('I go to "(.*?)"', function (url) {
        browser.get(url);
    });

    this.When('The URL of the page should be "(.*?)"', function (url) {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);
    });

};
```

Change your step defition file as below **(if you use Cucumber 2 or above)**

```
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');

defineSupportCode(function ({ Given, When, Then }) {

    Given('I go to "(.*?)"', function (url) {
        browser.get(url);
    });

    When('The URL of the page should be "(.*?)"', function (url) {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(url);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I have upgrade the version of protractor to 5.2.2. and updated chromedriver using the command 'webdriver-manager update' and solved that issue.but still the browser is not taking the given url and it shows the below error .

Comment: Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module 'F:\frx-automation\pretty'

Comment: Change your cucumberOpts as my answer above.

Comment: I have made the changes as you said.Now the browser is closing within a second and still the given url is not taking instead it gives a code result of feature file along with 
[19:11:14] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[19:11:14] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[19:11:14] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[19:11:14] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Comment: Is there any mistake in my step definition file

Comment: I have made the changes but getting the same issue.I am using cucumber 3.2.0.I don't understand where i am wrong.

Comment: getting the error
[09:50:05] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[09:50:05] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[09:50:05] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[09:50:05] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1

Comment: You used the latest Cucumber, but write the step definition with lower verions' syntax, please refer to https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md to learn how to write step definition with new syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your reply..I have modified the step definition file as
var {defineSupportCode} = require('cucumber');
var seleniumWebdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

defineSupportCode(function({Given}) {
 Given('I go to {string}', function (string) {
  browser.get(string); 
 }); 
});

but when i run 'node_modules\.bin\cucumber-js' it gives an error
ReferenceError: browser is not defined at World.<anonymous>

Comment: Hi guys, I almost teach you step by step. I think it's not a correct way for you to learn thing.  To run protractor script you must use command: protractor  <your config file>, for example protractor conf.js.  No matter you use Jamsine or Cucumber to write test case.